# Android ViewModel do not propagate data

Tags: java, android

Suddenly I decided that need to gain android dev experience. I want to create a simple us which will get data from lib and push it to segment with the table view. I'm following the guide https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

The problem is that I don't have exceptions but the data in the table(R.id.sdkhash) is not updated. There should be some stupid mistake on my side, but I can't find it.

**MainActivity.java**
I'm getting (InfoViewModel extends ViewModel) here and push the data via selectItem method.

```java
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
infoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(InfoViewModel.class);
RuntimeInfo runtimeInfo = new RuntimeInfo("A", "B", "C", "D"); 
infoViewModel.selectItem(runtimeInfo);

InfoViewModel.java
class RuntimeInfo {
    public String sdkHash;
    public String deviceUid;
    public String URL;
    public String userAgent;

    public RuntimeInfo(String hash, String deviceid, String url, String agent) {
        sdkHash = hash;
        deviceUid = deviceid;
        URL = url;
        userAgent = agent;
    }
}
```

**InfoViewModel.java** I'm defining my ViewModel here.

```java
class RuntimeInfo {
    // Dummy class to hold the data.
    public String sdkHash;
    public String deviceUid;
    public String URL;
    public String userAgent;

    public RuntimeInfo(String hash, String deviceid, String url, String agent) {
        sdkHash = hash;
        deviceUid = deviceid;
        URL = url;
        userAgent = agent;
    }
}

public class InfoViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<RuntimeInfo> selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<RuntimeInfo>();
    public void selectItem(RuntimeInfo item) {
        selectedItem.setValue(item);
    }
    public MutableLiveData<RuntimeInfo> getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }
}
```

**InfoFragment.java** - Fragment which is responsible for the UI part. I want to be able to update its UI based on the data from MainActivity.

```java
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
...
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    hashRowview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sdkhash);
    infoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(InfoViewModel.class);
    infoViewModel.getSelectedItem().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
        hashRowview.setText((CharSequence) item.sdkHash);
    });

    infoViewModel.getSelectedItem();
    RuntimeInfo runtimeInfo = infoViewModel.getSelectedItem().getValue();
    System.out.println("*************************************** runtimeInfo:" + runtimeInfo);
    if (runtimeInfo != null) {
        hashRowview.setText((CharSequence) runtimeInfo.sdkHash);
        System.out.println("*************************************** runtimeInfo Not NULL");

    }
```

Comment: `new ViewModelProvider(this)` i don't think you're creating a viewmodel with the same context or, at the very least, you're creating two different viewmodel instances, right ? you have one underneath `onCreate` and also one near `onViewCreated`

Comment: instantiate viewModel in fragment and use the same instance to update and retrieve Live data.

Comment: @ArpitPatel In case I'm creating a data source(3rd party library) instance in MainActivity. How to pass it to the viewModel in a fragment?

Comment: @greggyNapalm Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel